# How to use a proxy with in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, http-proxy

I need to use a proxy with HtmlAgilityPack.
I give a link to my app `RefURL`. After that I want the app get url from a proxy address. For instance "101.109.44.157:8080"

I searched and found out this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(host,port);
var page = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

and used it like this.

```
RefURL = new Uri(refLink.Text);

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("101.109.44.157:8080");
var page = wc.DownloadString(RefURL);

RefURL.ToString();
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(RefURL.ToString());
```

but it does not work!

Comment: `it does not work!` is no sufficient description.

Comment: It cant serve the link via the proxy

Comment: The proxy is not responding. You need fresh proxy IP list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proxy IP is not responding but also you're not passing web proxy in this code line:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(RefURL.ToString());
```

Should be:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(RefURL.ToString(),"GET", webProxy);
```

First step is finding **"fresh proxy IP"** list, for example:

- https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list/
- https://free-proxy-list.net/uk-proxy.html
- https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/
- http://free-proxy.cz
- http://nntime.com

Most of these addresses would work for few hours. Check out [how to set proxy IP in a browser](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows/). If the proxy is anonymous, [this page](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) should be unable to detect your location and IP.

Once you have a proxy IP and port that works, you can create webProxy object or simply pass IP and port.

```
string RefURL = "https://www.whatismyip.com/";
string myProxyIP = "119.81.197.124"; //check this is still available
int myPort = 3128;
string userId = string.Empty; //leave it blank
string password = string.Empty;
try
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load(RefURL.ToString(), myProxyIP, myPort, userId, password);
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(RefURL.ToString(),"ip", port,"","");`

Thanks for your replay. I got this error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Unable to connect to the remote server`

Comment: Need new proxy server as explained in comments. These IPs are being blancklisted periodically and hence must be changed.

Comment: I used a new proxy. it works fine with firefox or ie.